# PHPUnit test if method is a static method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit

How do I test if a method is static with phpunit?

I have a static method `\ProcessWire\className::getModuleInfo` and I want to add a test to make sure it is static. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to test that? IMO, there is no value in such a test. Unless, of course, you are working on a code generator and want to verify its output.

Comment: For testing if I can call the method static instead of creating a new instance of a class before I can call it?

Comment: If you cant call statically a method, php runtime will throw an exception. You do not need a test to do this. This is an attempt to test php. You do not need to test php, you need to test only your domain code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) to confirm that a method is `static`

```
<?php
class Apple {
    public function firstMethod() { }
    final protected function secondMethod() { }
    private static function thirdMethod() { }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Apple');
// Only return method data that is a static method
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC);
// shows information only for `thirdMethod()`
var_dump($methods);
```